loading Yolov9 model trained on custom dataset: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
I have trained a yolov9 model on custom dataset for instance segmentation, now I want to get segmentation area after segmentation.
An output like the given below image but for each and every object segmented in the image.

from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import torch
import cv2


model = torch.hub.load('.', 'custom', path='yolov9-inst/runs/train-seg/gelan-c-seg15/weights/best.pt', source='local') 
# Image
img = 'WALL-INSTANCEE-2/test/images/5a243513a69b150001f56c31_emptyroom6_jpeg_jpg.rf.7aa8f6a9aefbb1c76adc60a7b392dcd6.jpg'
# Inference
res = model(img)

But I am getting this error while finding res only.
YOLO  v0.1-104-g5b1ea9a Python-3.10.12 torch-2.1.0+cu118 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA RTX A5000, 24248MiB)

Fusing layers... 
gelan-c-seg-custom summary: 414 layers, 27364441 parameters, 0 gradients, 144.2 GFLOPs
WARNING ⚠️ YOLO SegmentationModel is not yet AutoShape compatible. You will not be able to run inference with this model.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[84], line 6
      4 img = 'WALL-INSTANCEE-2/test/images/5a243513a69b150001f56c31_emptyroom6_jpeg_jpg.rf.7aa8f6a9aefbb1c76adc60a7b392dcd6.jpg'
      5 # Inference
----> 6 results = model(img)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1518, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1516     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1517 else:
-> 1518     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1527, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1522 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1523 # this function, and just call forward.
   1524 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1525         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1526         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1527     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1529 try:
   1530     result = None

File /workspace/yolov9-inst/./models/common.py:868, in DetectMultiBackend.forward(self, im, augment, visualize)
    866 def forward(self, im, augment=False, visualize=False):
    867     # YOLO MultiBackend inference
--> 868     b, ch, h, w = im.shape  # batch, channel, height, width
    869     if self.fp16 and im.dtype != torch.float16:
    870         im = im.half()  # to FP16

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

Please can anyone help me to resolve this issue

please read the error message. why did you pass a string to the model, instead of a picture? -- this has got nothing to do with OpenCV. please do not tag OpenCV when the issue doesn't involve it.

Thank You for your advice but earlier I was passing the picture but I was getting an error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3).
And I got this code from github where he also passed path of the image as input
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/discussions/5872

The model expects an image in the form of a NumPy array or a tensor, but you're passing a file path as a string directly. You need to read the image from the file first and then pass it to the model.
Something like this:
 # Image path
img_path = 'WALL-INSTANCEE-2/test/images/5a243513a69b150001f56c31_emptyroom6_jpeg_jpg.rf.7aa8f6a9aefbb1c76adc60a7b392dcd6.jpg'

# Read the image using OpenCV
img = cv2.imread(img_path) # height, width, channel
img = img.swapaxes(0,2)    # channel, height, width
img = np.expand_dims(img,0) # batch, channel, height, width

and then pass the img to your model
# Inference
res = model(img)


Hello thank you for your response, earlier I tried this only but I was getting an error
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
And the code that I have had written i.e passing the path of image in the model to find result is something that I have had got from github
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/discussions/5872

Have you tried creating a batch with the image?  --> 868     b, ch, h, w = im.shape  # batch, channel, height, width is telling us in what format it is expecting the image. I have modified my answer. I hope this helps.

Thanks a lot but I am still getting error
